# Difference between & and && in PHP

Tags: php

I am confused with `&` and `&&`. I have two PHP books. One says that they are same, but the another says they are different. I thought they are same as well.

Aren't they same?

Comment: They are both the same thing, they're just used for two different things to accomplish the same task.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

`&` is bitwise AND. See [Bitwise Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). Assuming you do `14 & 7`:

```
    14 = 1110
     7 = 0111
    ---------
14 & 7 = 0110 = 6
```

`&&` is logical AND. See [Logical Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). Consider this truth table:

```
 $a     $b     $a && $b
false  false    false
false  true     false
true   false    false
true   true     true
```

Comment: I'll add that when you are comparing booleans or integers, and treating the result as a boolean, then they *appear* to be the same.

Comment: @kibibu: true, PHP's type juggling can complicate the comparison.

Comment: @kibibu, Does the interpreter consider them equal? Or will different machine code be runned depending on which one is used?

Comment: @Pacerier They are definitely different -- look at the return results in the example.  In a boolean context (an if statement), the correct branch is taken, but other than that there is nothing one borrows from the other.  Except at the bit level..

Comment: @kibibu not necessarily at all. 2 & 1 (binary 10 & 01) is 0 which is falsey, but 2 && 1 should be true if PHP is at all reasonable...

Answer (score 62):

The other answers are correct, but incomplete.  A key feature of logical AND is that it short-circuits, meaning the second operand is only evaluated if necessary.  The PHP manual gives the following example to illustrate:

```
$a = (false && foo());
```

`foo` will never be called, since the result is known after evaluating false.  On the other hand with

```
$a = (false & foo());
```

`foo` will be called (also, the result is 0 rather than false).

Answer (score 9):

[Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376348/difference-between-and-in-php/3964189#3964189) about how *Logical And* `&&` operator is the biggest difference; logical comparison will stop when it will find something that breaks the chain. In addition, one more big difference it the *result type/value*.

### *tl;dr*

By using the *Logical And* `&&`, it will always return a *Boolean type/value*, `true` or `false`.

```
false & 1 // int(0)
false && 1 // bool(false)
```

It is important to use *Boolean type/values* when returning a function with a logical result, because someone can use the *Identical comparison operator* `===` to compare the results (which is high likely to happen) and it will fail if you use something like this:

```
(false & 1) === false // bool(false)
(true & true) === true // bool(false)
```

Never use *Bitwise And* `&` when you need to make a logical comparison and especially when returning values from functions with logical results. Instead use the *Logical And* `&&`:

```
(false && 1) === false // bool(true)
(true && true) === true // bool(true)
```

When comparing characters, *Logical And* `&&` will always result to `true`, even with `NUL` character, unless if it's converted to an integer:

```
'A' && 'B' // bool(true)
'A' && 0 // bool(false)
'A' && '\0' // bool(true)
'A' && (int)'\0' // bool(false)
```

If you use the *Bitwise And* `&` with characters, it will result the character corresponding to the *Bitwise And* operation between those two characters:

```
'A' & 'B' // string(1) "@"

01000001 // ASCII 'A'
&
01000010 // ASCII 'B'
=
01000000 // ASCII '@'
```

Beware the usage of the *Bitwise And* `&` when using with types other than *Integers* and *Characters* (which are special kind of integers). For example, if you use it with real numbers *float/double*, then it can result to `0` even if both operands are *NOT* `0`:

```
1.0 & 1.0 // int(1)
2.0 & 1.0 // int(0)

1.0 && 1.0 // bool(true)
2.0 && 1.0 // bool(true)
```

In addition, if we go at assembly instructions level, we can see that difference and how the compiler manages to handle so the *Logical And* `&&` uses `cmp <var>, 0` to compare and does not continue executing if one operand fails; *Bitwise And* uses `and <var1>, <var2>` to make a bitwise result and then test if it's of `0` value. I know this question is tagged for [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [php](/questions/tagged/php) behavior may be different than [c](/questions/tagged/c), but I'll use a small [c](/questions/tagged/c) program to demonstrate how compiler behaves when using *Logical* and *Bitwise And*.

Let's assume we have a program in [c](/questions/tagged/c) that uses both *Bitwise* and *Logical And*:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 2;

if (a & b)
    c = 3;

if (a && b)
    c = 4;
```

The compiler will generate the following assembly opcodes (*W32Dasm result for x86*; I have changed the memory addresses with `<variable>` names for simplicity and to be more understandable):

```
:0229  mov <a>, 0
:0230  mov <b>, 1
:0237  mov <c>, 2
// if (a & b) begins
:023E  mov eax, <a>
:0241  and eax, <b>        // a bitwise and b, result stored to eax
:0244  test eax, eax       // test eax and set ZeroFlag if equals to 0
:0246  je 024F             // >---  Jump if ZeroFlag is set
:0248  mov <c>, 3          //    |  or set c = 3
// if (a && b) begins            |
:024F  cmp <a>, 0          // <---  compare a to 0 and sets ZeroFlag if difference is 0
:0253  je 0262             // >---  Jump if ZeroFlag is set (a == 0)
:0255  cmp <b>, 0          //    |  compare b to 0 and sets ZeroFlag if differemce is 0
:0259  je 0262             //    |  >--- Jump if ZeroFlag is set (b == 0)
:025B  mov <c>, 4          //    |     | or set c = 4
:0262  <program continues> // <---  <---
```

The compiler not only uses different instructions to compare between the *Logical* and *Bitwaise And*, but at the line `:0253` in `if (a && b)` logical comparison, we see that if `a == 0` then it jumps and does not check for the rest operands.

So, I disagree to [animuson's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376348/difference-between-and-in-php#comment2352750_2376348):

> They are both the same thing, they're just used for two different
>   things to accomplish the same task. – animuson Mar 4 '10 at 1:42

They are not the same thing and both are/*(should be)* used for specific tasks depending on the programs' logic/flow.

Answer (score 7):

```
 

AND operation: 

& -> will do the bitwise AND operation , it just doing operation based on
      the bit values. 
&&   -> It will do logical AND operation. It is just the check the values is 
       true or false. Based on the boolean value , it will evaluation the 
       expression
```

Comment: what is the difference between logical and boolean bitwise? they are the same.

Comment: @avasin Logical `AND` performs a short-circuited (see Matthew Flaschen's answer) `and` operation on *the boolean values* of its operands and evaluates to a boolean value, whereas bitwise `AND` performs the `and` operation on *each individual bit* of each of its operands. So `0b0011 && 0b0110` evaluates to `TRUE`, but `0b0011 & 0b0110` evaluates to `0b0010`.

Comment: @avasin there is no *boolean bitwise* operation.

Answer (score 3):

As the others are saying, a single `&` is bit-wise. It basically converts the left-hand value into its bits representation, and the right hand side into bits representation as well, then performs logical AND between them and outputs the result.

Double `&&` is either true or false, (in some languages 0 or 1) if both left and right side are true (or non-zero).

I'd also add that this is not just in PHP. It is like that in many many other languages as well, like C, Java, [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29), etc.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is `&` performed on operands reduced to either `1` or `0`.

(In other words, `&&` is a bitwise operator under the caveat that it changes its operands. That is, logical operations are a subset of bitwise operations.)