# Meaning of only one & and | on php

Tags: php

I've seen this expression and I don't know it's meaning

```
chr(ord($uuid[6]) & VALUE1 | VALUE2);
```

It's only using one & and | .

Comment: Another question to look at is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705838/when-should-i-use-a-bitwise-operator

Comment: bitwise operator