# How can I add multiple & conditions in if statement in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to multiple & conditions in if statement in Codeigniter. If I use 2 conditions like below:

```
#<?php if (trim($var1) == '' & trim($var2) == '') : ?>#
```

Then it works fine. But if I add another & condition like

```
#<?php if (trim($var1) == '' & trim($var2) == '') & trim($var23) == ''): ?>#
```

Then it shows error.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this extra bracket,

```
(trim($var1) == '' && trim($var2) == '') && trim($var23) == ''):
                                       ^
```

Also here you need logical operator `&&` and not bit-wise operator `&`. Check here to see the difference between them.

[**difference between & and && in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376348/difference-between-and-in-php)