# Check multiple variables (boolean) in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using this in my code but I think it can be improved and can be done a simpler way?

```
if($phaseOne == true && $phaseTwo == true && $phaseThree == true) {

}
```

Comment: Get rid of all of the `== true` as they are not necessary

Comment: `===` for identical comparison

Comment: Sometimes nested if's are better as you can quicker reject the whole code. Say $phaseOne is false. In your one line code it will still try all three. If you nested it with `if ($phaseOne){ if ($phaseTwo){ }}` the code will fail at the first try

Comment: Put them in an array and iterate over them.  Old programming wisdom says "2 or more, use a for"

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

```
if($phaseOne && $phaseTwo && $phaseThree) { ... }
```

Or use [`ternary operator`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), if you're trying to define a variable on the basis of these conditions like this:

```
$var = ($phaseOne && $phaseTwo && $phaseThree) ? true : false;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array with an arbitrary number of logical variables:

```
$logical = array($phraseOne,$phraseTwo,....);
$allTrue = array_reduce($logical, function ($x,$y) {return $x && $y;},true);
if($allTrue) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do just:

```
if($phaseOne && $phaseTwo && $phaseThree)
```

Comment: It's better to [add more context/explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) around code (as opposed to just having a code-only answer) as that makes the answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compare it against true.

```
if ($phaseOne && $phaseTwo && $phaseThree) {

}
```

This occurs because the result of any comparison is a boolean:

```
var_dump(1 == 1); // bool(true)
var_dump(1 == 2); // bool(false)
```

Also if you variable contains a number, it can be used directly:

```
if (1) {
     // This will be executed
}

if (0) {
     // This will not be executed
}
```

Zero will be always be treated as `false`, any other number (positive or negative) will be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to check each variable as explicitly identical to a boolean or variable, ([see this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp))

I'd do it this way

`if ($phaseOne && $phaseTwo && $phaseThree) {}`

Otherwise, I'd do it this way

`if ($phaseOne === true && $phaseTwo === true && $phaseThree === true) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
 ($phaseOne && $phaseTwo && $phaseThree) ? {//do something} : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I think it is arbitrary, controlversial, trivial, and won't preach the use of this, just for fun and learning - here's some typical php variable type juggling that will work also and takes up the least space... efficient in terms of source code length.

```
if($phaseOne*$phaseTwo*$phaseThree) { ... }
```

Comment: the difference is that all values need to accessed unconditionally, whereas by using `&&` or `||` operators, you gain the efficiency of an early "short circuit" and thus less potential evaluations.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964189/2943403