# is there a way to compare multiple values in php

Tags: php

My code below is sending me the email even if this statement isn't true  if($value['flagS']=='Yes'& $value['flagE']=='Yes' & $value['flagL']=='Yes' & $value['flagML']=='Yes') see my code below and assist, where am i going wrong

```
  $flagquery = "SELECT * FROM approved"; 

        try 
        { 

        $stt = $db->prepare($flagquery); 
        $stt->execute(); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 

        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 


        $rows = $stt->fetchAll(); 

        foreach($rows as $value):

        if($value['flagS']=='Yes'& $value['flagE']=='Yes' & $value['flagL']=='Done' & $value['flagML']=='Done'){


        $message = "your request was approved <br/>                     
                                            <br /><br />";

        $subject = "Application $identifier has been approved ";

        $email="xx@xxx.co.xx";


        send_mail($email,$message,$subject);


Blockquote
```

Comment: You can use in_array() function for this

Comment: `&` does __not__ do what you expect. What you expect does `&&`.

Comment: you've missed one `&` for logical `AND` operation. It should be `&&`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376348/difference-between-and-in-php

Comment: Ideal situation would be that your **database** tells you whether request was approved or not. You can do the same truth check in your query and create a true/false flag. Then you can avoid this clusterf*** sausage in your PHP and keep it readable.

Comment: you have too many unaccepted answers

Answer (score 1):

Please be careful, I don't think your condition does what it's supposed to do. Using a single `&` is a [bitwise operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) when you probably want `&&`, i.e. a [logical operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

```
if($value['flagS'] == 'Yes'
   && $value['flagE'] == 'Yes'
   && $value['flagL'] == 'Yes'
   && $value['flagML'] == 'Yes'
) { ... }
```

This will now check all 4 flag values (S, E, L, ML) for "Yes" and only then return true.

Answer (score 0):

To write it in more optimised way.

```
$keys_to_match = ['flagS', 'flagE', 'flagL', 'flagML'];
foreach($rows as  $key => $value) {

   if(in_array($key , $keys_to_match) && $value[$key] ==='Yes') {

     // ....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use && in if condition

AND operation:

& -> will do the bitwise AND operation , it just doing operation based on
      the bit values. 
&&   -> It will do logical AND operation. It is just the check the values is 
       true or false. Based on the boolean value , it will evaluation the 
       expression

Answer (score 0):

I used to design flags with bit operations.

```
define("flagS", 1);
define("flagE", 2);
define("flagL", 4);
define("flagML", 8);
define("allFlags", 15); // join all flags (flagS | flagE | flagL | flagML)
```

It needs less space in db and you can check the flags very easy without expensive loops.
If a single flag is set, use

```
if($storedFlags & flagS) {
    //Flag flagS is set
} else {
    // Flag is not set
}
```

If more than one is set, use

```
$required = flagE | flagML;
if( ($storedFlags & $required) == $required) {
    // Flags flagE and flagML are set
} else {
    // No or only one flag is set
}
```

To check if all are set, simply replace $required with allFlags or 15, if the count of flags does not change.