# AJAX Uploading Image on form submit

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to upload an image with some other variables and on the form submit, do my php code to save the image to the users `profile_picture` table.

I want to make my image upload in the same form as saving my data changes.

This is a picture of what it looks like so you can have a better understanding :

[image: IMAGE HERE]

I did it before where I used the POST method, but for AJAX i'm not sure how to do it.

My Javascript code is (note that this doesn't work, I just tried having a go - It returns `Illegal invocation` in the console.log) :

```
<script>
function updateMyAccount() {
  var fd = new FormData($("#fileinfo"));
  var password = document.getElementById("myAccountNewPassword").value;
  var profilePicture = document.getElementById("myAccountNewProfilePic").value;

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "includes/form_submit.php",
      data: {
        SaveAccountChanges: true,
        securePassword_Val: password,
        fd
      },
      success: function(msg){
        if(msg == 1) {
          update_myAccount_success();
        } else {
          general_error_forms();
        }
      },
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
```

My PHP code is :

```
//My account AJAX POST
if(($_POST['SaveAccountChanges']) == true & isset($_POST['securePassword_Val']))
{
    $member_config->doUpdateAccountInfo($con);
}
```

Then my function to upload the image and save it to the database :

```
function doUpdateAccountInfo($con)
{
    //Upload users image to our /uploads directory
    $uploaddir        = 'uploads/';
    $uploadfile       = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
    $save_to_database = ("uploads/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $normalPassword   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["securePassword_Val"]);
    $pwd              = password_hash($normalPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $username         = $_SESSION["username"];

    if(!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']) & !empty($_POST['securePassword_Val']))
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {} else { die('Could not upload file.<br>Contact the Administrator of the website for more infomration.'); }
        $query = "UPDATE users SET password = '$pwd', profile_picture = '$save_to_database' WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('error');
        echo '<div class="panel -success"><div class="panel-body"><p>You have successfully updated your <b><i>password and profile picture</i></b>!</p></div>';
        //echo '1';
    }
    else if (empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']) & empty($_POST['securePassword_Val']))
    {
        $query = "UPDATE users SET password = '$pwd' WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('error');
        echo '<div class="panel -success"><div class="panel-body"><p>You have successfully updated your <b><i>profile picture</i></b>!</p></div>';
        //echo '1';
    }
    else if (empty($_POST['securePassword_Val']) & !(empty($_FILES['fileToUpload'])))
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) { echo 'Successfully uploaded image'; } else { die('Could not upload file.<br>Contact the Administrator of the website for more infomration.'); }
        $query = "UPDATE users SET profile_picture = '$save_to_database' WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('error');
        echo '<div class="panel -success"><div class="panel-body"><p>You have successfully updated your <b><i>password</i></b>!</p></div>';
        //echo '1';
    }
    else if (empty($_POST['securePassword_Val']) & empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']))
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('error');
        //echo '<div class="panel -danger"><div class="panel-body"><p>You have failed to update your <b><i>password and profile picture</i></b>!</p></div>';
        echo '0';
    }
    else
    {
        //echo '<div class="panel -danger"><div class="panel-body"><p>An error occured!</p></div>';
        echo '0';
    }
}
```

I have looked a the link that was posted and now have this code :

```
<script>
function updateMyAccount() {

  var fdata = new FormData($("#data"));
  fdata.append("securePassword_Val",$("#myAccountNewPassword").val());
  fdata.append("SaveAccountChanges",true);

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "includes/form_submit.php",
      data: 
        //SaveAccountChanges: true,
        //securePassword_Val: password,
        fdata
      ,
      async: false,
      success: function(msg){
        if(msg == 1) {
          update_myAccount_success();
        } else {
          general_error_forms();
        }
      },
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
```

***How would I go about making the image upload through this method ?***

Comment: plenty of questions here on how to upload a file with Ajax.

Comment: The [`FormData` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) does not accept a jQuery object but a native form element. In your case, you would have to use [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) to add the file.

Comment: @Mikey Okay thanks. Do you have an example ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax

Comment: @epascarello I have now updated the code at the bottom. How would I go about making my selected image upload using this method ?

Comment: var fdata = new FormData($("#data")); <-- you have a jQuery object, form Data has no clue what a jQuery object is, it wants DOM.

Comment: Contrary to the linked answer, do not use [async: false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1478322/1022914). It defeats the whole purpose of using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I wouldn't answer this question because it gets asked many times. But I see few issues in your code, so I'm going to make an attempt.

**JavaScript**

(1) Ensure that you have included jQuery script

(2) Ensure that you have a `form` element (preferrably give it an ID attribute e.g. `myform` for referencing) and all your inputs have `name` attributes.

(3) Pass the native form element (not jQuery object) into `FormData` constructor. This will allow you to pass all the input elements with `name` attributes from your form -- so you don't need to manually add them. Exception is your `SaveAccountChanges` field that you want to pass, here you need to use `FormData.append()`.

(4) Set $.ajax `data` option to only the FormData object. Set `contentType` and `processData` options to `false`.

```
    function updateMyAccount() {
        // document.getElementById('myform') === $("#myform")[0] === myform
        var fd = new FormData($("#myform")[0]);
            fd.append('SaveAccountChanges', true);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/form_submit.php",
            data: fd,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg == 1) {
                    update_myAccount_success();
                } else {
                    general_error_forms();
                }
            },
        });

        return false;
    }
```

And this should be the minimum that you need on the client-side. When debugging, use your browser's web tools.

**PHP**

(6) Turn on your [PHP error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

(7) Learn the difference between [&& and &](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2376353/1022914) -- they are not the same.

(8) Because you are uploading using FormData, you need a stronger validation for your upload fields. `$_FILES['fileToUpload']` will not be empty even when you don't select a file.

Comment: Thank you so much! Brilliant answer.