# How to check if a product is created by a user in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good Day, i'm trying to check if a product is created by a user and if no, the add to cart button should be removed.

I'm working on a store whereby a registered user can create product from frontend. I added this argument to create the product from frontend;

```
$post = array(
        'post_author' => $currentCOUser_ID // This Return the User's ID using wp_get_current_user()->ID
        'post_status' => "publish",
        'post_excerpt' => $pProduct_excerpt,
        'post_title' => $ProductTitle,
        'post_type' => "product",
    );

    //create product for product ID
    $product_id = wp_insert_post( $post, __('Cannot create product', 'izzycart-function-code') );
```

When product is created i only want the author and admin to be able to see the add to cart button on the product single page. I used the below code but didn't work;

```
function remove_product_content() {
    global $post;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $product_author_id = $current_user->ID;
    $admin_role = in_array( 'administrator', (array) $current_user->roles );


    //check if is a product & user is logged in and is either admin or the author
    //is a product and user is not logged in, remove add to cart
    //is a product and user is logged in and not either admin or product author, remove add to cart button
    if ( is_product() && is_user_logged_in() && (!$admin_role || $product_author_id != $post->post_author)  ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_product_content' );
```

when i run the above code, it completely hide the add to cart button from everyone. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an ampersand. It should be `&&`. `&` is a bit wise AND. See this link for more details on the difference between the two: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2376353/10987825

Also, wrap the `||` portion of the statement in parentheses. Otherwise, as long as the current user is not the author, it will be hidden. Check these two links to see the difference.

[Incorrect Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ed9c698ccea0f903425f4c256077675739feb50)

[Correct Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b993f737284fa509e51d5e25f7fa4fc60826898)

So your code would become:

```
function remove_product_content() {
    global $post;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $product_author_id = $current_user->ID;


    //check if is a product & user is logged in and is either admin or the author
    //is a product and user is not logged in, remove add to cart
    //is a product and user is logged in and not either admin or product author, remove add to cart button
    if ( is_product() && (!is_user_logged_in() || (!is_admin() && $product_author_id != $post->post_author)) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_product_content' );
```

Comment: i have added the ampersand and yet, the add to cart button doesn't show [updated my code]

Comment: I’ve updated my answer. I think you need parentheses around the “or” statement otherwise it is sort of like “(a and b) or c

Comment: Still not working, i have created another user and created product from frontend with the user who is not an admin, yet cant view the add to cart button as the Product Author

Comment: Come to think of it, based on your question it should be an &&. You want it to be hidden if “a product page and (either not logged in or (not an admin and not the author ))

Comment: I've done that but not working and i was able to figure out that is_admin() doesn't check if user is administrator [as seen here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/). I have updated my code to detect administrator (which worked). I think the culprit here is the `$product_author_id != $post->post_author` , as this doesn't check if the user is author. This is where i need help now

Comment: It looks like you’re saving the user display name. You should save the user ID instead.

Comment: i just modified the code to save the user ID and not the display name and it worked. Thanks. Will update my code