# Bitwise operators in PHP

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

Are in PHP the single `|` and the keyword `OR` equivalent?

Analogously, are the single `&` and the keyword `AND` equivalent?

Comment: [No](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), the word operators are logical operators, not bitwise operators, so they'll work a bit differently.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376348/difference-between-and-in-php has a bit more information. The previous link shows that `AND` and `OR` have a lower precedence than `&&` and `||`, but [work the same](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between & and && in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376348/difference-between-and-in-php)