# Is $isAdmin * $isLogin * $isConfirmed a good practice to check if one of them is false? instead of using if statement

Tags: php

As the title, Is the code below, a good practice to check if one of the variables is false?

```
return $isAdmin * $isLogin * $isConfirmed;
```

Instead of using if statement that is shown below.

```
if (!$isAdmin | !$isLogin | !$isConfirmed) {
    return false;
}
```

I'd like to know why if it's not.

Comment: Both statements are perfectly equivalent.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to multiply things together? Assuming based on your variable names that you have booleans, they will be cast to the integer `1` or `0` for `true` or `false`, which works, but you could skip the cast and just use an `&&`. Similarly, if they are ints or even numeric strings, although a Boolean cast will happen, it (arguably) reads easier as “and” instead of “times”.

Comment: @Air this is worth a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964189/2943403 to benefit from short circuiting.

Comment: && is more standard/semantic and will result in fewer evaluations due to how it short circuits.